# Could not find XXXXXXX simulator

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

The last 2 days I've been banging my head on this, and since I had to dig through gitHub issues to find my fix, I'm putting it here so it will hopefully help someone else.

I can run all of the other simulators I use, but recently have found some UI bugs specific to the iPad Pro 11-inch model. So I've been trying to launch that simulator specifically to no avail. I'm getting this error:

```
error Could not find iPad Pro (11-inch) (6F2D27E4-32D8-4B7D-B268-1B0713EB97F1) simulator. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
```

I tried logging the steps in the `react-native run-ios` findMatchingSimulator.js file. Could not figure out what was going on, but logging my devices list there showed a ton of inactive devices, plus the list of active devices I knew.

Running `xcrun simctl list devices` gave me the following output.

```
== Devices ==
-- iOS 12.2 --
    iPhone 5s (C5826171-13BE-41EA-901B-7B43696C3C01) (Shutdown)
    iPhone 6 (BD534AAE-6F9B-4C84-AC46-4D3CD247FEAE) (Shutdown)
    iPhone 6 Plus (089315D2-EE75-4A3F-A4B2-8740D4756277) (Shutdown)
    iPhone 6s (5691F6FD-608D-48EF-A7E9-817E17EE7AF3) (Shutdown)
    iPhone 6s Plus (42D3F69D-6647-4C27-9B06-E2D85589152C) (Shutdown)
    iPhone 7 (7D564E89-7860-4A39-9BB2-7CF03FAB7554) (Shutdown)
    iPhone 7 Plus (9004541C-4555-4D54-8516-09F5EAA37130) (Shutdown)
    iPhone 8 (C77E9475-668B-4FBC-AFDF-A9988DD9F43C) (Shutdown)
    iPhone 8 Plus (F908AFA2-2BF0-4ADC-A4F6-ED32F76125F7) (Shutdown)
    iPhone SE (6D7A9107-A67F-4684-B5B8-99FC3BED357E) (Shutdown)
    iPhone X (9619A1FF-5ECC-4672-B760-CB27D3303D2D) (Shutdown)
    iPhone Xs (5C32E392-2721-4B63-A096-82C4A548D603) (Shutdown)
    iPhone Xs Max (701C2CCE-388B-4D7D-8C7C-2954BBC72461) (Shutdown)
    iPhone Xʀ (DBEAAE0F-AF30-4198-AECB-5A62A4179028) (Shutdown)
    iPad mini (5th generation) (1A96F4E4-FD2E-49E1-A93C-1FF10F229355) (Shutdown)
    iPad Air (3rd generation) (88ACC19B-6F49-457E-8B15-6B337E026EFC) (Shutdown)
    iPad Air (F35E0A98-AEB9-49FA-BE9E-0C36E37B615E) (Shutdown)
    iPad Air 2 (6D647415-2903-42DA-A90E-F6067B9B47C7) (Shutdown)
    iPad (5th generation) (16B5F02E-90E9-41E7-AA2B-FA4E605C8AF4) (Shutdown)
    iPad Pro (9.7-inch) (63360396-407D-461F-8D62-243D584EB6C9) (Shutdown)
    iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (9A220CF0-0BA6-4F98-B395-4343F20FD124) (Shutdown)
    iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (2nd generation) (0C7F2F61-74C8-4B51-92DB-B3EA5D26A03A) (Shutdown)
    iPad Pro (10.5-inch) (6BF39DD9-806B-442B-AE26-10854EB0FF96) (Shutdown)
    iPad (6th generation) (0DAA2D70-D814-4B8E-ACB3-B7238CB6AA1F) (Shutdown)
    iPad Pro (11-inch) (6F2D27E4-32D8-4B7D-B268-1B0713EB97F1) (Booted)
    iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (3rd generation) (CCDC4BD6-72B9-4CB5-A809-960F08B39E4F) (Shutdown)
-- tvOS 12.2 --
    Apple TV (8A172120-ED91-4B54-84EA-19CC25363740) (Shutdown)
    Apple TV 4K (3E104BFD-D8B3-42BC-AD3F-743DDEFF1BCC) (Shutdown)
    Apple TV 4K (at 1080p) (B1BCC24F-7D88-4710-8EC8-3F01EFBBB5B5) (Shutdown)
-- watchOS 5.2 --
    Apple Watch Series 2 - 38mm (8D48AA77-4C92-4135-B8B9-48830933E555) (Shutdown)
    Apple Watch Series 2 - 42mm (693BDC3F-BAB1-46C3-8AAC-BDF507F4A3F4) (Shutdown)
    Apple Watch Series 3 - 38mm (5857A791-2C83-410F-9672-3A28B6E85170) (Shutdown)
    Apple Watch Series 3 - 42mm (80282B84-D01E-4399-9235-61B74370EB22) (Shutdown)
    Apple Watch Series 4 - 40mm (DC520F96-889A-468A-8C0D-4DE52FA2164A) (Shutdown)
    Apple Watch Series 4 - 44mm (6FB6B0DC-F63E-4A27-8F74-FE500286368B) (Shutdown)
```

As you can see, the simulator I tried running is in this list, but I still get an error trying to run `react-native run-ios` while specifying that simulator.

After walking through all kinds of GitHub issues, I happened upon a fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix was noted because the user with the fix had multiple devices in different OS's. I don't have that, all mine that show up are in the same OS, 12.2, but I figured I'd give it a try.

I change my iPad Pro 11-inch alias from:

```
react-native run-ios --simulator='iPad Pro (11-inch)'
```

to:

```
react-native run-ios --simulator='iPad Pro (11-inch) (12.2)'
```

and voila, it works. I'm guessing that the deactivated ipad 11 that is a different OS was the problem, but search me as to why my other simulators work, since they also had deactivated dupes in different OS's.